# MotionEvent Action_Up issues on passing event

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, motion-detection

I have a top(transparant) view over my appliction.
this is supposed to catch a Long press of 5 seconds and open a menu . 
So i implemented an OnTouchListener . 
 like this :

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
                {       
                        long downtime = 0;
                        long eventt = 0;


                        boolean returnvalue = false; 

                        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) 
                        {

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                             eventt = event.getEventTime();                         
                             returnvalue = true; 
                             break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                            downtime = event.getDownTime();
                            if (eventt - downtime > 5000)
                            {
                                Main.changePlayerDialog.show();
                                returnvalue = true;
                            }
                            else
                            { 
                                returnvalue = false;
                                //return false;
                            }
                            break;

                        default: 
                                break;
                       }                

                        return returnvalue;

                    }
                });
```

now , for the 5 second touch and release this works just fine.
however , when its less then 5 ,I return false.
The MotionEvent however isn't passed down to other views beneath it !
so all buttons and such of underlying views are now 'disabled'  ...

If i return false straightaway everything works fine... but then the ACTION_UP doesn't trigger anymore if a underlying button has been triggered. (seems logical, event has been handled somewhere else).

how can i fix this  ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried returning :

```
return super.onTouch(v, event);
```

?

--- Edit

Well, if you do so :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="coucou"
        android:id="@+id/button" />


    <LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And add onTouch on linear layout and on click on button, the button will never catch the event...

Comment: I get a StackOverFlowError at android.view.MotionEvent.getEventTime(MotionEvent.java:1389)

Comment: Well, the problem is that you can't touch a view that is under an other view... check my edited message...

Comment: actually, you can.
If you pass false on the upper one it gets passed down.
Like i said, everything works fine if I return false straightaway.

Comment: Ok, but thats cause you had you child have something like "duplicateParentState" ?

Comment: nothing like that really.
 same as for example a listview with buttons. Basic build up. 
EVen if i just add a blank view ontop, it still passes thru my events.